# WordPress Google Maps in Custom Theme

Tags: theme-development, jquery, google-maps

So I'm building a custom theme and implemented the Google Map API so I can give it a cleaner feel and so on then the normal Google Map.

I've run into a problem when implementing my Marker as I implement the marker through jQuery but I can't seem to find a way to get the folder my marker is in.

Somehow in my jQuery file I need to get the stylesheet directory uri and then locate my marker

**Updated**: Solution Below

map.js:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    //set your google maps parameters
    var latitude = 52.4680166,
        longitude = -1.8922481,
        map_zoom = 16;

    // Marker Location
    var marker_url = WPD.stylesheet_dir + '/assest/imgs/map/cd-icon-location.png';
```

functions.php:

```
// Locate Map Marker
function wpd_scripts() {

    // Fetching the Location
    wp_enqueue_script (
        'wpd_script',
        get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/assest/imgs/map/cd-icon-location.png',
        null,
        null,
        false
    );

    // Localize the Marker
    wp_localize_script (
        'wpd_script',
        'WPD',
        array(
            'stylesheet_dir' => get_stylesheet_directory_uri()
        )
    );

}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpd_scripts' );
```

Comment: This question is suitable for Stack Overflow because it has nothing to do with WordPress core.

Comment: But I'm trying to locate the WordPress directory within JavaScript so it is WordPress related really

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enqueue your script and use `wp_localize_script` to pass data.

```
function wpd_scripts() {

    wp_enqueue_script(
        'wpd_script',
        get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/script.js',
        null,
        null,
        false
    );

    wp_localize_script(
        'wpd_script',
        'WPD',
        array(
            'stylesheet_dir' => get_stylesheet_directory_uri()
        )
    );

}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpd_scripts' );
```

You can then use `WPD.stylesheet_dir` in your script to get the value you set in PHP.

```
var marker_url = WPD.stylesheet_dir + '/assest/imgs/map/cd-icon-location.png';
```

Comment: I have a question within my JavaScript how would I call the WPD.stylesheet.dir would I include it within the where the quote marks are. `'WPD.stylesheet.dir/assest/imgs/map/cd-icon-location.png'` or out like this`WPD.stylesheet.dir'/assest/imgs/map/cd-icon-location.png'`

Comment: So I did this instead `'WPD.stylesheet.dir'` and that didn't seem to work. I changed the location in the function of where the icon is and still didn't work. I've updated my code above to show to see if you can see where I'm making the mistake. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: It's a [javascript object](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_objects.asp). `WPD` is the object name, `stylesheet_dir` is the property name (note that is an underscore NOT a dot). So it's `WPD.stylesheet_dir`, no quotes.

Comment: Yeah the dot was a typo my bad xD I don't think I put my question across that well to be honest, what I mean is how do I called `WPD.stylesheet_dir` inside my map.js which is in a completely different location to my functions.php
As in my JavaScript file I have added the `WPD.stylesheet_dir` and the marker still doesn't show in the map :/

Comment: `WPD.stylesheet_dir` is the path to your stylesheet directory. You need to append `/assest/imgs/map/cd-icon-location.png` to that value. See edit above. Or you can pass the full URL of your image from PHP, it's up to you.

Comment: Arr that works great. So WPD.stylesheet_dir is the link to my stylesheet then from there I locate my marker and inside the js I + the reset of the link towards my mark and then my marker_url does the rest of the work and implements it into my map. I apprentice your help on this Milo :) Thank you again broke down a wall I couldn't get past